# NGINX блокировка по реферу

Tags: nginx

Нужно заблокировать клиентов с плохим *рефером*. Читаю, оказывается для этого нужен модуль [`ngx_http_referer_module`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html).

Потом в другом месте вижу использование встроенной переменной [`$http_referer`](https://rusadmin.biz/bloknot/blokirovka-dostupa-s-opredelyonnogo-sajta-ban-po-referer/)

Это устаревшая информация и теперь работает только первый вариант? Или могу банить по второму варианту, не имея модуля `ngx_http_referer_module`?

Answer (score 1):

`$http_referer` вполне подходит. Сам им пользуюсь:

```
if ($http_referer ~* (redirect.php|redirect.asp|out.php) ) {
     return 405;
}
```

Еще могу предложить ссылку на [официальную документацию](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/refererspam/), где используется модуль `valid_reference`.